# [Catel]How do I pass a ViewModel with constructor argument(s) to TabServiceExtensions methods?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

So I've just started out using Catel this past week but I'm having trouble getting a tabbed interfaced working. I've been using the following resource *Using a tabbed interface with MVVM* (https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Using+a+tabbed+interface+with+MVVM#UsingatabbedinterfacewithMVVM-CreatingClosableTabItem):

I have a MainWindow (catel:Window) which contains a TabControl with *xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:AutoProgram.UI.Controls"*:

```
<Border Background="#50FFFFFF" BorderBrush="{StaticResource WindowFrameBrush}" BorderThickness="5" Margin="-6" Padding="0">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="{StaticResource WindowFrameBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="0,0,0,0" Margin="0" Padding="0">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,2,10,2" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Title}"/>
                <Button Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="1" FontSize="7" Width="15" Height="15" Padding="0" Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <catel:StackGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <catel:StackGrid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </catel:StackGrid.RowDefinitions>
            <catel:StackGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </catel:StackGrid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControlAutomators" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Automators}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="3" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="Button" Content="{Binding Automator.Name, Mode=OneWay}" Command="{Binding ElementName=ItemsControlAutomators, Path=DataContext.RunAutomator}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </catel:StackGrid>

        <catel:TabControl x:Name="TabControlAutomators" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="-2" LoadTabItems="LazyLoading">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:ClosableTabItem Title="{Binding ViewModel.Title}" CanClose="{Binding CanClose}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel, Converter={catel:ViewModelToViewConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </catel:TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Relevant MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var serviceLocator = this.GetServiceLocator();
        var tabService = serviceLocator.ResolveType<ITabService>() as TabService;

        tabService?.SetTabControl(TabControlAutomators);
    }
}
```

Relevant MainWindowViewModel.cs and **location of failure**:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IAutomatorService _automatorService;
    private readonly ITabService _tabService;

    public MainWindowViewModel(IAutomatorService automatorService, ITabService tabService)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => automatorService);
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => tabService);

        _automatorService = automatorService;
        _tabService = tabService;

        RunAutomator = new Command<AutomatorModel>(OnRunAutomator, OnRunAutomatorCanExecute);
    }

    public override string Title => "AutoProgram";

    public ObservableCollection<AutomatorModel> Automators
    {
        get { return GetValue<ObservableCollection<AutomatorModel>>(AutomatorsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AutomatorsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData AutomatorsProperty = RegisterProperty("Automators", typeof(ObservableCollection<AutomatorModel>), () => new ObservableCollection<AutomatorModel>());

    public Command<AutomatorModel> RunAutomator { get; private set; }

    public async void OnRunAutomator(AutomatorModel automatorModel)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"NAME: {automatorModel.Automator.Name}");
        _tabService.AddAndActivate<AutomatorViewModel>(new AutomatorViewModel(automatorModel), true);   // Throws a null exception in TabItem.cs
        //_tabService.AddAndActivate<AutomatorViewModel>(new AutomatorViewModel(), true);   // But this works (sort of, see bottom error).
    }

}
```

TabServiceExtensions.cs

```
public static class TabServiceExtensions
{
    public static TabItem Add<TViewModel>(this ITabService tabService, object dataContext = null, bool canClose = false)
        where TViewModel : IViewModel
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => tabService);

        var tabItem = CreateTabItem<TViewModel>(tabService, dataContext);
        tabItem.CanClose = canClose;

        tabService.Add(tabItem);

        return tabItem;
    }

    public static TabItem AddAndActivate<TViewModel>(this ITabService tabService, object dataContext = null, bool canClose = false)
        where TViewModel : IViewModel
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => tabService);

        var tabItem = Add<TViewModel>(tabService, dataContext, canClose);
        tabService.Activate(tabItem);

        return tabItem;
    }

    public static TabItem CreateTabItem<TViewModel>(this ITabService tabService, object dataContext)
        where TViewModel : IViewModel
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => tabService);

        var dependencyResolver = tabService.GetDependencyResolver();
        var viewModelFactory = dependencyResolver.Resolve<IViewModelFactory>();
        var vm = viewModelFactory.CreateViewModel<TViewModel>(typeof(TViewModel), dataContext);

        return new TabItem(vm);
    }

    public static void AddAndActivate(this ITabService tabService, TabItem tabItem)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => tabService);
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => tabItem);

        tabService.Add(tabItem);
        tabService.Activate(tabItem);
    }
}
```

TabItem.cs

```
public class TabItem
{
    public TabItem(IViewModel viewModel)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => viewModel);

        ViewModel = viewModel;
        CanClose = true;

        if (!viewModel.IsClosed)
        {
            viewModel.ClosedAsync += OnViewModelClosed;
        }
    }

    public IViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }

    public bool CanClose { get; set; }

    public object Tag { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Closed;

    private async Task OnViewModelClosed(object sender, ViewModelClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = ViewModel;
        if (vm != null)
        {
            vm.ClosedAsync -= OnViewModelClosed;
        }

        Closed.SafeInvoke(this);
    }
}
```

I want the TabItems to be AutomatorViewModels. The latter is initialised as such:

```
    public AutomatorViewModel(AutomatorModel automatorModel)
    {
        Title = "Test";
    }
```

But the above code throws a null Exception in TabItem.cs. If I **omit** the constructor argument, i.e., change it to
*public AutomatorViewModel()*
the tab(s) do get created with "Test" titles. Although in that case get the following error when manually closing these tab(s):
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TabControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=TabStripPlacement; DataItem=null; target element is 'TabItem' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

App.xaml.cs

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        LogManager.AddDebugListener();

        Log.Info("Starting application");

        StyleHelper.CreateStyleForwardersForDefaultStyles();

        var serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.Default;
        serviceLocator.RegisterType<IAutomatorService, AutomatorService>();
        serviceLocator.RegisterType<ITabService, TabService>();

        // SOME THINGS I'VE TRIED/CURRENTLY TRYING.
        //var dependencyResolver = this.GetDependencyResolver();
        //var viewModelLocator = dependencyResolver.Resolve<IViewModelLocator>();
        //viewModelLocator.Register<AutomatorView, AutomatorViewModel>();
        //viewModelLocator.Register(typeof(AutomatorView), typeof(AutomatorViewModel));
        //viewModelLocator.Register<MainWindow, MainWindowViewModel>();

        Log.Info("Calling base.OnStartup");
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
```

---

Catel debugging info:

11:22:39:117 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.ViewModelBase] [8] Creating view model of type 'AutomatorViewModel' with unique identifier 2

11:22:39:117 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.ViewModelCommandManager] [8] Creating a ViewModelCommandManager for view model 'AutoProgram.UI.ViewModels.AutomatorViewModel' with unique identifier '2'

11:22:39:118 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.ViewModelCommandManager] [8] Created a ViewModelCommandManager for view model 'AutoProgram.UI.ViewModels.AutomatorViewModel' with unique identifier '2'

11:22:39:119 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.ManagedViewModel] [8] Added view model instance, currently containing '1' instances of type 'AutoProgram.UI.ViewModels.AutomatorViewModel'

11:22:39:123 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [8] Creating instance of type 'AutoProgram.UI.ViewModels.AutomatorViewModel' using specific parameters. No constructor found in the cache, so searching for the right one

11:22:39:124 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [8] Checking if constructor 'public ctor(AutomatorModel automatorModel)' can be used

11:22:39:126 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [8] Constructor is not valid because value 'AutoProgram.UI.ViewModels.AutomatorViewModel' cannot be used for parameter 'AutoProgram.UI.ViewModels.AutomatorViewModel'

11:22:39:126 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [8] The constructor is valid and can be used

11:22:39:127 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [8] No constructor could be used, cannot construct type 'AutoProgram.UI.ViewModels.AutomatorViewModel' with the specified parameters

11:22:39:128 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [8] Creating instance of type 'AutoProgram.UI.ViewModels.AutomatorViewModel' using specific parameters. No constructor found in the cache, so searching for the right one

11:22:39:128 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [8] Checking if constructor 'public ctor(AutomatorModel automatorModel)' can be used

11:22:39:129 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [8] Constructor is not valid because parameter 'automatorModel' cannot be resolved from the dependency resolver

11:22:39:129 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [8] The constructor is valid and can be used

11:22:39:130 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] [8] No constructor could be used, cannot construct type 'AutoProgram.UI.ViewModels.AutomatorViewModel' with the specified parameters

11:22:39:130 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.ViewModelFactory] [8] Could not construct view model 'AutoProgram.UI.ViewModels.AutomatorViewModel' using injection of data context 'AutomatorViewModel'
AutoProgram.UI.vshost.exe Error: 0 : 11:22:39:131 => [ERROR] [Catel.Argument] [8] Argument 'viewModel' cannot be null
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in Catel.Core.dll

---

### EDIT #1:

- added debugging info (uncommented *LogManager.AddDebugListener();*)
- added App.xaml.cs

---

### EDIT #2:

Found a workaround by changing the view model's initialisation to a constructorless one, and setting the model property explicitly, as follows:

_tabService.AddAndActivate(new AutomatorViewModel { AutomatorModel = automatorModel }, false);

Answer (score 0):

You should pass in the *DataContext* object, not the *ViewModel* into the `AddAndActivate`. So this should work (and will construct & inject the vm for you):

```
_tabService.AddAndActivate<AutomatorViewModel>(automatorModel, true);
```

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't work. Same debugging errors. I don't know how and where to register a viewmodel parameter. I'm also having asynchronous issues with the nested tabcontrol. Cheers anyway.